# Order By chronological order FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I am unable to order the quarter and year in FOR XML Path by chronological order.Although I am ordering it doesn't work.Can some one let me know where I am going wrong

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
    LON.DATE
    ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT   ',' + 'Q' + (COALESCE(CAST(LON1.QTR AS Varchar(10))+ '/ ', '') + + CAST(LON1.YR AS Varchar(10))) 
           FROM LOANTABLE LON1
           WHERE LON.DATE = LON1.DATE 
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS QuarterAndYear
FROM 
   LOANTABLE LON
GROUP BY 
   LON.DATE
ORDER BY 
   QuarterAndYear
```

This is the result data:

```
Date               QuarterAndYear
2011-04-01         Q1/ 2008,Q3/ 2009,Q1/ 2010,Q2/ 2009,Q4/ 2009,Q2/ 2008,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q3/ 2008,Q4/ 2008,Q4/ 2010,Q1/ 2011,Q2/ 2011,Q1/ 
2009 2010-12-01    Q1/ 2010,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q4/ 
2010 2011-07-01    Q1/ 2010,Q3/ 2011,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q4/ 2010,Q1/ 2011,Q2/ 
2011 2012-01-09    Q1/ 2010,Q3/ 2011,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q4/ 2011,Q4/ 2010,Q1/ 2011,Q2/ 
2011 2011-07-08    Q1/ 2010,Q4/ 2009,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q4/ 2010,Q1/ 2011 –
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data please?

Answer (score 0):

Use following format:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT LON.DATE
                ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT   ',' + 'Q' + (COALESCE(CAST(z.QTR AS Varchar(10))+ '/ ', '') + + CAST(z.YR AS Varchar(10))) 
                       FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT QTR, YR
                             FROM LOANTABLE LON1
                             WHERE LON.DATE = LON1.DATE
                             ORDER BY LON1.QTR DESC
                             )z
                       FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS QuarterAndYear
FROM LOANTABLE LON
GROUP BY LON.DATE
ORDER BY QuarterAndYear
```

Comment: Its still not working.Its displaying the quarter and years randomly since my date LON.DATE field is date only field and it doesn't have any time .

Comment: This is the data i get
'2011-04-01   Q1/ 2008,Q3/ 2009,Q1/ 2010,Q2/ 2009,
Q4/2009,Q2/2008,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q3/ 2008,Q4/ 2008,Q4/ 2010,Q1/ 2011,Q2/ 2011,Q1/ 2009
2010-12-01   Q1/ 2010,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q4/ 2010
2011-07-01   Q1/ 2010,Q3/ 2011,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q4/ 2010,Q1/ 2011,Q2/ 2011
2012-01-09          Q1/ 2010,Q3/ 2011,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q4/ 2011,Q4/ 2010,Q1/ 2011,Q2/ 2011
2011-07-08          Q1/ 2010,Q4/ 2009,Q2/ 2010,Q3/ 2010,Q4/ 2010,Q1/ 2011'

Comment: @suryabhai. what sort you want on your data.

Comment: The data i am getting in the result set right now is like this -Q1/2010,Q2/2009,Q3/2014.The actual result should be in an orderly way like Q3/2014,Q1/2010,Q2/2009.It should be in chronological order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56865/discussion-between-mehdi-lotfi-and-suryabhai).